# CustomizableOutDir=true breaks MSTest.exe during Team Build

Tags: tfs, mstest, tfsbuild

When using CustomizableOutDir, I'm having problems with TFS Team Build firing off MSTest.exe properly.

TFSBuild.rsp

```
/verbosity:diagnostic
/p:CustomizableOutDir=true
```

TFSBuild.proj (solutions to build snippet)

```
    <!-- code -->
    <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../foo.csproj">
      <Properties>OutputPath=$(BinariesRoot)\WindowsServices\foo\</Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>
    <!-- tests -->
    <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../test/test.sln">
      <Targets>t1;t2</Targets>
      <Properties>OutputPath=$(BinariesRoot)\TestHarness\</Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>
```

With both `<Properties>OutputPath=$(BinariesRoot)\TestHarness\</Properties>` and `<Properties></Properties>`, I get the following error at the end of the build:

> "C:\build\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj"
>   (TestConfiguration target) (1:12) ->
>   (CoreTestConfiguration target) ->
>   MSBUILD : warning MSB6003: The
>   specified task executable "MSTest.exe"
>   could not be run. The directory name
>   is invalid

After finding [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/8ea0d57f-97ac-43a5-b265-09632a12a138), I and then added the following:

```
  <Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <ItemGroup>
      <SolutionOutputs Condition="'%(CompilationOutputs.Solution)' == '$(Solution)'" Include="%(RootDir)%(Directory)**\*.*" />
      <ServiceOutputs Include="$(BinariesRoot)\WindowsServices\**\*.*" />
      <TestHarnessOutputs Include="$(BinariesRoot)\TestHarness\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SolutionOutputs)" DestinationFolder="$(TeamBuildOutDir)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ServiceOutputs)" DestinationFolder="$(TeamBuildOutDir)"  />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(TestHarnessOutputs)" DestinationFolder="$(TeamBuildOutDir)"  />
  </Target>
```

Which gave this:

> (AfterCompile target) ->
>   C:\build\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(289,5):
>   error MSB3023: No destination
>   specified for Copy. Please supply
>   either "DestinationFiles" or
>   "DestinationDirectory".

DestinationDirectory is not part of the schema `http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003`, but I figured I would try it anyway.  So I changed all the `DestinationFolder` on the copy tasks to `DestinationDirectory` and as expected I got this:

> (AfterCompile target) ->
>   C:\build\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(288,44):
>   error MSB4064: The
>   "DestinationDirectory" parameter is
>   not supported by the "Copy" task.
>   Verify the parameter exists on the
>   task, and it is a settable public
>   instance property.
>   C:\build\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(288,5):
>   error MSB4063: The "Copy" task could
>   not be initialized with its input
>   parameters.

Anybody out there have CustomizableOutDir and MSTest working together in harmony with their TFS Team Build?

EDIT:

I found [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/6ced3395-6c8d-4f49-93db-80c49ad1cad9) and applied this change:

```
<Target Name="BeforeTest">
  <!-- The tests won't run if the binaries directory does not exist -->
  <MakeDir
    Directories="$(BinariesRoot)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)"
    Condition="!Exists('$(BinariesRoot)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)')" />
</Target>
```

Which resulted in this:

> "C:\build\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj"
>   (RunTest target) (1:11) ->
>   "C:\build\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj"
>   (TestConfiguration target) (1:12) ->
>   (CoreTestConfiguration target) ->
>   MSBUILD : warning MSB6006:
>   "MSTest.exe" exited with code 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This made tfs/mstest/msbuild happy.

```
<Target Name="BeforeTest">
  <!-- The tests won't run if the binaries directory does not exist -->
  <MakeDir
    Directories="$(BinariesRoot)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)"
    Condition="!Exists('$(BinariesRoot)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)')" />
</Target>
```

Not getting any test results was a different problem with the deployment and test box configuration.